# Photoshop Express Alternative

Tags: windows, gratis, image-editor

Does anyone know of a Photoshop Express Alternative? You can only get the App store version for Windows, which obviously is an app, and I want a program.

Basically I am looking for a Image Editor that can:

- Crop Images
- Rotate and Flip
- Ability to edit brightness
- Ability to edit contrast
- Simple to use
- Ability to use filters (though this is not necessary)

Photoshop Express fits the bill perfectly, just it isn't an `exe`

The OS is Windows, and needs to be backwards compatible, that's why I need a 'non-app' program, as it will need to work on windows 7.

It needs to be very simple - a shallow learning curve.

Comment: May be this Paint.NET or GIMP which is image and photo editing software Windows.

Comment: @Vembu those are exactly why I wanted simple - I need a program with a very shallow learning curve. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like [Pixlr](https://pixlr.com/desktop) from Autodesk. It's very simple and straightforward. You can crop images, rotate, resize, brighten, and add fun effects (like turning the whole picture black and white except a certain object). It's free and it is a .exe.

[image: Pixlr Example]

Answer (score 1):

There are many simple photo editors out there available for Windows:

## [Picasa](https://picasa.google.com/)

It's a photo organiser and editor by Google that boasts lots of filters as well as basic editing functions including brightness, contrast cropping, rotating, etc.

[image: picasa]
<sub>(source: [anonymousoft.com](http://anonymousoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Picasa-3.9-Build-137.118-Full-Version-Free-Download1.jpg))</sub>

## [Photoscape](http://www.photoscape.org/ps/main/index.php)

> PhotoScape is a fun and easy photo editing software that enables you to fix and enhance photos.

[image: photoscape]

## Windows Live Photo Gallery

This is actually part of Windows Live Essentials and might already be installed on your system but shouldn't be overlooked. It does have most of the features you describe (except possibly flipping, though I'm not certain)

[image: windows photo gallery]
<sub>(source: [staticworld.net](http://zapp2.staticworld.net/downloads/graphics/screenshots/71287f.jpg))</sub>